# How to append value from a dictionary to list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I have a dictionary d

```
d = {'word': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], 'data':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'mark': [1,4,5,2,5,6,7]}
```

and a data frame containing lists

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({data:[
              ['data', 'customer', 'mark', 'hello', 'spam', 'life'], 
              ['from','the', 'word', 'mark', 'data'], 
              ['hello', 'word', 'mark', 'data', 'the']]}, 
              index = [0,1,2]))
```

In the above df code, the words are split in 6 columns, one word for each column, but in my actual example, they are all in one column, and its one big list.

I want to match the words from each list of the dataframe to the keys in the dictionary. If the word occurs, append the respective values from the dictionary to the word in the dataframe, and if not, omit the word from the list.

The output should look something like this:

```
new_df = [[[data,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [mark,1,4,5,2,5,6,7]], 
          [[word,0,1,2,3,4,5,6], [mark,1,4,5,2,5,6,7], [data, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8]], 
          [[word,0,1,2,3,4,5,6], [mark,1,4,5,2,5,6,7], [data, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]]
```

because in the first list, we do not have the words `customer`, `hello`, `spam`, `life` in the original dictionary. Similarly, in the next list, we dont have the words `from`, `the` and so on...

What is the best way to achieve this?

I did something like this:

```
def checkkey(dict, key):
if key in dict.keys():
    key.append(dict[key])
else:
    print("Not present")


checkkey(d,a)
```

where d is this dictionary and `a ='data'`

How do I do this for all the words in the list and the entire dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reformatted the dataframe you specified in the question. I think this is what you were looking for :

```
d = {'word': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], 'data':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'mark': [1,4,5,2,5,6,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame({"data":[['data', 'customer', 'mark', 'hello', 'spam', 'life'],['from','the', 'word', 'mark', 'data'],
                   ['hello', 'word', 'mark', 'data', 'the']]})
```

[image]

Solution:

```
def check_word(x,d):
    return [[i,d[i]] for i in x if i in d]
            
df['data'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x:check_word(x,d))

print(df.data.values)

# ---- Output -----
# array([list([['data', [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]], ['mark', [1, 4, 5, 2, 5, 6, 7]]]),
#   list([['word', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], ['mark', [1, 4, 5, 2, 5, 6, 7]], ['data', [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]]),
#   list([['word', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], ['mark', [1, 4, 5, 2, 5, 6, 7]], ['data', [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]])],
#  dtype=object)
```

Comment: This is what I wanted, check the word first, and if it exists, and the values from the dictionary. Next step further, if i wanted to take column means for each of these list of lists, how do you suggest, i do that? The simple sum/ len gives me 1 value, whereas I expect to see 7 values for each row. ie. [1.5 , 3.5, 4.5, 3.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5] for the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Create the dataframe like this:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({'data': [
                 ['data', 'customer', 'mark', 'hello', 'spam', 'life'], 
                 ['from','the', 'word', 'mark', 'data'], 
                 ['hello', 'word', 'mark', 'data', 'the']]}, 
                 index = [0,1,2]))

>>> df
                                       data
0  [data, customer, mark, hello, spam, life]
1              [from, the, word, mark, data]
2             [hello, word, mark, data, the]
```

Use:

**Approach1:**

```
df =  (df['data'].apply(lambda x: 
                [[name] + d[name] for name in x if name in d]))
>>> df
0    [[data, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [mark, 1, 4, 5, ...
1    [[word, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [mark, 1, 4, 5, ...
2    [[word, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [mark, 1, 4, 5, ...
```

---

**Approach2:** If you have unique values in each list then you can use:

```
df = (df['data'].apply(lambda x: [[name] + d[name] 
                    for name in set(x).intersection(d)]))
```

This might be little bit faster.

---

**Approach3:**
`.apply` is usually slow so I am posting one more approach without using apply. Though it looks like that there are more operations here but most probably this is faster than `.apply`.

First let's change dictionary to have key in the value list.

```
d = {k: [k] + v  for k, v in d.items()}
>>> d
{'word': ['word', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'data': ['data', 2, 3, ...
```

Not first explode dataframe to put each value of list in new row.

```
df1 = df.explode(column = 'data')

>>> df1
           data
    0      data
    0  customer
    0      mark
    0     hello
    0      spam
    0      life
    1      from
    1       the
    ...
```

Now do mapping and then combine the row using index.

```
 df1.data = df1.data.map(d)
 df1 = df1.dropna()
 df1 = df1.groupby(df1.index).agg(lambda x: x.tolist())

>>> df1
                                                data
0  [[data, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [mark, 1, 4, 5, ...
1  [[word, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [mark, 1, 4, 5, ...
2  [[word, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [mark, 1, 4, 5, ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, the first approach is similar to the accepted answer and works the best. I didnt try approach 3, because of the explode function. My original data has 1M rows and 300 columns for values, and I dont know the number of words within each list.